# Modify Geonetwork 3.4.2 to show Thesaurus themes keywords

Tags: geonetwork

What I need to do is show the keywords of a local thesaurus on the home screen, similar to how the topicCats are displayed.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add thesaurus xsl parsing into a file for a specific schema, for example in this file: `schemas/iso19139/src/main/plugin/iso19139/index-fields/default.xsl`

Then you need to add this field into facets; you can do it in this file: `web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config-summary.xml`.
After changing this file run index rebuild (and other reindex related stuff) in the admin panel

At the end modify home template: `web-ui/src/main/resources/catalog/views/default/templates/home.html`.

For easier task check how it is done to inspire thesaurus, so search in the project for this keyword: `inspireThemeURI.`